EF Core is not creating a MigrationsHistory table
I've been using Entity Framework Core for some time with my app. And I just noticed, there is no MigrationsHistory table. I looked at the files in core/Migrations and none of them create a MigrationsHistory table.
Why is it missing and how do I get it?
And how do I populate it with the correct values for the 3 (so far) migrations I have created?
The SQL script script-migration created does try to insert a row into __EFMigrationsHistory. This fails as the table does not exist.

It may seems obvious: But have you called dotnet ef database update. Only with this command beeing called, the migration table will be created in the database.

@decius I do not. I call AppDbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync() to create the database (months ago) and then for updates I generate the SQL script, review it, then run it.
